# Adding classes to single_cat_title();

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to add different class name for each single_cat_title(); in wordpress?
Can I do that anyway?

I use that code

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
```

and I want to set class name `.show` to h1 when opened category named SHOW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the category title name for every individual category,

```
<h1 class="<?php single_cat_title(); ?>"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
```